# Best way to reverse parent tr ordering stack in a table via jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a table that is populated from a .net app that produces the following content...

```
<table>
<tbody>
...
<tr>...anything below...
  <table>
  <tbody id="blahlkjasdblah">
    <tr><td> 
    lots of custom content
    </td></tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
</tr>
<tr>...anything below...
    <div id="something">
    <table id="othertable">
    <tbody>
      <tr><td>
      lots of other custom content that is different
      </td></tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

What is the best way to reverse `**these first two parent only**` `<tr>` **NOT NESTED TABLES OR TR blocks**, this way the one on the bottom is on top of the 1st one?

Thanks

Comment: Hi blachawk, by "best" do you mean fastest code execution or cleanest to write/maintain?

Comment: @jmbertucci i would like a little of both :) but cleanest would be good.

Comment: I found the consideration of "best" to be the more interesting question. I threw this virtual napkin fiddle together to try and see what really would be "best". http://jsfiddle.net/YfufZ/4/ I theorized that appending nodes over and over would be slower than just replacing the entire HTML, but it seems the accepted answer tends to come in the fastest.  While using the ".each()" function is the slowest.  At least, if I setup my simple tests right.

Comment: dystroy, PSL, wirely, Lukasz, Lech, Edwin Alex, this is "not" a duplicate question - I am asking to modify the parent tr elements (only).  not nested tr elements.  @Kevin B was the "only one" of all developer who answered my specific question correctly.

Comment: @blachawk KevinB answered the question correctly, yes, but this really is a duplicate, there's no notable difference.

Comment: So what you guys want me to do since you are convinced this is a duplicate question.  Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `[].reverse` method.

```
[].reverse.call($("#myTable > tbody > tr")).appendTo("#myTable > tbody");
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NujhC/)

or turn it into a jquery plugin:

```
$.fn.reverse = [].reverse;
$("#myTable > tbody > tr").reverse().appendTo("#myTable > tbody");
```

Comment: is that going to look for every tr or just the first two parent tr's ?

Comment: All tr's that are in the tbody.

Comment: i need the to modify the parent tr's only

Comment: parent tr's? i don't understand. parents of what? all tr's are parents of table cells.

Comment: First and Last tr's only?

Comment: this is what i mean: within the 2nd tr, I have another table in there.  I don't care about that nested table that is inside the 2nd parent tr.  I just want to reverse the 2 parent trs.  does that make sense?

Comment: Ah nested tables. Just modify the selector to only target the parent tr's. change incoming...

Answer (score 7):

```
 var $body = $('tbody');    
 var list = $body.children('tr');
 $body.html(list.get().reverse());
```

Demo `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/kYwk9/

Answer (score 3):

```
table = $('tbody');
table.children().each(function(i,li){table.prepend(li)});
```

Answer (score 3):

The best way would be to change the way this table is generated in the first place. I imagine that currently that's being done server side based on an iteration through a list of elements. Instead, switch to a client side rendering that uses an AJAX call to gather this list of elements so that the javascript has access to it. Create the necessary templating code to render the list in the table. When you want to reorder the rows perform the operation on the list of elements itself and then rerun the templating code.

Comment: I imagine the reason he's asking is because he doesn't have access to the .net app

Comment: Maybe, but that might not be the case for all who see this question.

Comment: @SpencerRuport you are right, but the current .net developers at the moment, have their hands tied and I need to give a quick answer for a project manager.  So yes I agree with you and have it planned, but thank goodness for jQuery :)

Comment: @blachawk - For sure. Just wanted to give this perspective in case it was an option for you or for anyone else who reads this question. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
tbody = $('tbody');
tbody.children().each(function(i,tr){
    tbody.prepend(tr);
});
```

It goes through each `tr` element and `.prepend()`s it to the `tbody` which results in them all being reversed.

Here's a working version: http://jsfiddle.net/Ybyjx/